# How to calculate the the elements of the arrays separately

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays "Resulted from the SQL query"

The first array is

```
Array ( [0] => 100 ) Array ( [0] => 200)
```

The second array is

```
Array ( [0] => 300 ) Array ( [0] => 400)
```

How to calculate the first elements of each arrays (`100` + `300`) and the second elements of the second arrays (`200` + `400`) separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sum = array(); 
for ($i=0;$i<count(array1);$i++) {
$sum[$i] = array1[$i] + array2[$i]; 
} 
print_r($sum);
```

=====Update======

```
<?php
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
echo "sum(a) = " . array_sum($a) . "\n";
$b = array("a" => 1.2, "b" => 2.3, "c" => 3.4);
echo "sum(b) = " . array_sum($b) . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to solve someone's problem for him, if there's no effort shown.

Comment: Thank you roshan lal, I really appreciate!
I was on my way coming back that' why I did not reply yet.. I will test the code now and let you know... Thanks again!

Comment: Hey roshan lal,

Are you sure about this line (($sum[$i] = array1[$i] + array2[$i];))
seems it not corrent. I tried it but its showing me an error.

Comment: its now working after I add $ sign.

Now is there any way to calculate the total of both array1 and array2?

Comment: Total of array1 like we have array(0=>100,1=>200) and result you are seeking is 100+200 =300

Comment: Yes, But can it be done Total of array1 + array2 example: (100+200)+(300+400)= 10000. is it possible to get the total like this? Thanks 100+200

Comment: Yes it's possible. I'm updating my answer

Comment: @John please refer PHP manual there you can get everything you want.

Comment: @roshan lal I really tried PHP manual before you said but its always showing me 0 0 this is my code


`$sum2 = array(); 
for ($i=0;$i<count($data_real_price);$i++) {
$sum2[$i] = $data_real_price[$i] * $temp_rows22_qty[$i]; 
} 

$a = array($data_real_price);
echo "sum(a) = " . array_sum($a) . "\n";

`

This is the output of my code "sum(a) = 0 sum(a) = 0 sum(a) = 0"

Comment: No problem, keep trying. Thanks